# What should I do with a cracked titanium Lemond Tete De Course frame?

Tags: frames, titanium

I have a 2002 titanium Lemond frame.  Just found a crack on down tube. Bummed to not be able to ride it anymore.  Is it worth trying to repair (if it's even possible)?

Comment: You'd need to find a frame builder who is specialized in titanium frames to see if a repair can be done. A picture would help to assess if its reasonable to go through that trouble depending on where you live.

Comment: We can't really answer this without a photo showing the damage clearly.  You're right that riding it is unsafe so don't.  Do you know if its gradual damage (ie a weakness) or sudden damage from a crash?    At the end of the day, get a quote for repair and see if its "worth" doing, weighing up the replacement cost and so on.

Comment: It's a heat treated frame, so the answer is very likely no. A repair will be difficult because of the need to back purge (fill the inside of the tube with argon while welding), and the heat treatment will be removed by welding so a repair will need to be large and probably ugly looking.

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I'll see if I can find local Ti repairman to get a quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting it fixed may cost more than the frame is worth and there's no guarantee it won't crack again. My husband's titanium Litespeed road frame cracked on the head tube twice. The first time, Litespeed replaced the frame.  The second time (cracked in almost the same spot as the first one) Litespeed said the frame had exceeded the "lifetime" of the lifetime warranty. He took it to a couple of welders but they said it would be $600 - $900 to fix (weld on a new head tube).

He gave the Litespeed frame to a welding student for parts/pratice and replaced it with a cheaper aluminum frame. Since he's not racing, he's not worried about a few extra ounces of weight in the frame and if it breaks he's only out a couple hundred dollars instead of a couple thousand.